# Multiple React rc-sliders ... no idea how to find out which one is actually changing

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable list of included services for my product and I have a rc-slider component for each of these services to de/increase the amount a users wants of each of the services (like training days, user licenses, ...)

I've got to the code below which gives me a slider for each of my services BUT ... each of the rc-sliders only return the numeric value of the slider but nothing for me to identify which slider is actually being changed.

```
    <ul className="included-services-amounts">
    {productIncludedServices.map( function(productIncludedService, i) {
        return (
          <li key={i}>
            <div>{productIncludedService.name}</div>
            <Slider dots min={productIncludedService.range[0]} max={productIncludedService.range[1]} step={1} defaultValue={10} onChange={updateIncludedServicesFunc.bind(this)} />
          </li>
        ) 
      })}
    </ul>
```

Sooo, is there any way to pass something more aside from "this" in

```
{updateIncludedServicesFunc.bind(this)}
```

or some alternative way to find out which slider component is actually getting changed?

Answer (score 0):

yup, there are several ways to do this.

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      method1(e) {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-params"));
      }
      method2 = params => {
        console.log(params);
      };
      method3(params) {
        console.log(params);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <button
              data-params="params from method 1"
              onClick={this.method1.bind(this)}
            >
              method 1
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.method2("params from method 2");
              }}
            >
              method 2
            </button>
            <button onClick={this.method3.bind(this, "params from method 3")}>
              method 3
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

[live demo on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yonmnx6q3)